# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'debug' Karma on $log object

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

When running my karma unit tests on my angular project, I'm running into errors on lines with `$log` defined.

I'm using Karma version: 0.10.1 and my config file is:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Aug 21 2013 14:10:06 GMT-0400 (EDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        '../build/angular/angular.js',
        '../build/angular/angular-mocks.js',
        '../build/angular/angular-resource.js',
        '../build/angular/angular-cookies.js',
        '../src/**/*.js',
        '../dist/tmp/**/*.js',
        '../vendor/angular-bootstrap/*.js',
        '../vendor/angular-ui-utils/modules/route/*.js',
        '../vendor/angular-ui-utils/modules/mask/*.js',
        '../vendor/angular-ui-utils/modules/event/*.js',
        '../vendor/angular-ui-utils/modules/keypress/*.js',
        '../vendor/moment/moment.js',
        '../vendor/Highcharts-3.0.2/highcharts.js',
        '../vendor/Highcharts-3.0.2/modules/exporting.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [

    ],


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9018,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: ['Chrome'],//nothing so we can start it on our own


    // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
    captureTimeout: 60000,


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
});
};
```

Comment: Could you show an example test (where `$log` is used)?

Comment: I don't use $log within the tests, it's whenever $log shows up in my normal javascript files. (Controllers, services, directors..)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the stable version of angular (currently 1.0.8) there is no method `$log.debug` (see [v1.0.8's $log documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/ng.%24log). `$log.debug` is only available from v1.1.2 onwards, [e.g. from v1.1.2's $log documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/docs/api/ng.%24log).

Best alternative would probably be `$log.log()`.

Comment: I'm using angular 1.1.5, but will see if this changes anything

Comment: Also check the version of angular referenced in your karma config

Answer (score 0):

Lorcan's identification of the problem is exactly correct but there is a better solution.  I just had this problem and it was rooted in inconsistencies in version upgrades.  I joined a project mid cycle.  This project started at angular version 1.0.*.  The project was eventually upgraded to angular 1.2.3.  The problem is that while the main lib directory was updated, the angular-mock.js file for unit tests was not.  The unit test were operating on the older version of angular in the mock file.  Go to http://code.angularjs.org/ and select the version of angular you are using.  Then replace your angular-mock.js with the one for you version of angular.  This resolved the .debug error.